# This a view in an App , I want to make this similar layout, can't seem where to start?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

I want make a similar layout with XML in Android studio, any one can how can make with similar layout, and and when one form completed another one opens , as you can see, one section is opened and as we click on next other section opens.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmvZ1.jpg)

Could help with a similar XML code

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

- Design the Toolbar
- Create the activity and take the parent layout as Linear Layout and set the weight to 3.
- Take the first child of this Linear Layout and mark it as Linear and similarly other layout will be linear.
- To have the expandable feature use this https://github.com/skydoves/ExpandableLayout.
- The input fields are just the normal EditTexts.